# What program can I use to detect protections used on a program and its libraries?

Tags: anti-debugging, packers, copy-protection, protection

What are some good programs that can detect which protection software has been used on or in other programs and their libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, try [Detect It Easy](http://ntinfo.biz/index.php/detect-it-easy). The project is alive and updated frequently.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [YARA](https://plusvic.github.io/yara/) with appropriates rules.
Or, if you're lazy, you can give a try to [radare2](http://rada.re), since it integrates YARA, and has a [shitload](http://radare.today/yara-support/) of packer-related rules. You could also grab the rule files [here](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/shlr/yara/packers.rules).

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best" I've used PEiD in the past which always worked pretty well.

http://woodmann.com/BobSoft/Pages/Programs/PEiD

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding a link to the mentioned program.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Protection ID](http://pid.gamecopyworld.com/) to be fast and comprehensive (last update in late 2013).